# Simple Server to PUSH lots of data to Browser?

Tags: websocket, push, mqtt, message-queue

I'm building a Web Application that consumes **data pushed from Server**.

Each **message is JSON and could be large, hundreds of kilobytes**, and messages **send couple times per minute**, and the **order doesn't matter**.

The Server should be able to **persist not yet delivered messages**, potentially **storing couple of megabytes** for client for couple of days, until client won't get online. There's a limit on the storage size for unsent messages, say 20mb per client, and old undelivered messages get deleted when this limit is exceeded.

Server should be able to handle around **1 thousand simultaneous connections**. How it could be **implemented simply**?

### Possible Solutions

I was thinking maybe store messages as files on disk and use Browser Pool for 1 sec, to check for new messages and serve it with NGinx or something like that? Is there some configs / modules for NGinx for such use cases?

Or maybe it's better to use MQTT Server or some Message Queue like Rabbit MQ with some Browser Adapter?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: An MQTT Broker will not queue up messages like you are wanting to do.  Something like Rabbit MQ or AMQ would be better suited for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, MQTT supports the concept of sessions that persist across client connections, *but* the client must first connect and request a "non-clean" session. After that, if the client is disconnected, the broker will hold all the QoS=1 or 2 messages destined for that client until it reconnects.

With MQTT v3.x, technically, the server is supposed to hold all the messages for all these disconnected clients forever! Each messages maxes out at a 256MB payload, but the server is supposed to hold all that you give it. This created a big problem for servers that MQTT v5 came in to fix. And most real-world brokers have configurable settings around this.

But MQTT shines if the connections are over unreliable networks (wireless, cell modems, etc) that may drop and reconnect unexpectedly.

If the clients are connected over fairly reliable networks, AMQP with RabbitMQ is considerably more flexible, since clients can create and manage the individual queues. But the neat thing is that you can mix the two protocols using RabbitMQ, as it has an MQTT plugin. So, smaller clients on an unreliable network can connect via MQTT, and other clients can connect via AMQP, and they can all communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

MQTT is most likely *not* what you are looking for. The protocol is meant to be lightweight and as the comments pointed out, the protocol specifies that there may only exist "Control Packets of size up to 268,435,455 (256 MB)" [source](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718023). Clearly, this is much too small for your use case.

Moreover, if a client isn't connected (and subscribed on that particular topic) at the time of the message being published, the message will never be delivered. **EDIT: As @Brits pointed out, this only applies to QoS 0 pubs/subs.**

Like JD Allen mentioned, you need a queuing service like [Rabbit MQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html) or [AMQ](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/7.0/html/using_amq_broker/addresses). There are countless other such services/libraries/packages in existence so please investigate more.

If you want to role your own, it might be worth considering using [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) and wrapping some of your own application logic around it. That'll likely be a bit hacky though, so take that suggestion with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew that MQTT don't guarantee message delivery, seems like Rabbit MQ is good fit for this case...

Comment: "at the time of the message being published, the message will never be delivered" - this is not necessarily correct. The MQTT broker will store messages for you as long as QOS1+, cleansession=0 and the client has previously connected. MQTT does provide Quality of Service guarantees; but these only kick in after the initial subscription from the client is received.

Comment: "I've even seen some brokers implement a cap of 65536 MB for message sizes" The maximum MQTT 3.1 publish packet is 2^28 bytes (256Mb) so I think you may have a typo there (not all brokers will support this; Mosquitto does). Anyway this is well over the OP's stated requirement.

Comment: @Brits you're absolutely right, thanks for pointing this out! I've updated my answer with the relevant documentation. As an aside, one thing I found interesting when reading the 5.0 MQTT spec is that it doesn't explicitly mention the 256MB limit like in 3.1.1, despite it being true in both versions.

Comment: @Mathyou MQTT 5 is similar (see [here](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.html#_Toc3901024) and [here](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.html#_Toc473619950)). The packets mentioned in the question are "hundreds of kilobytes" in size so I'm not sure why you say "this is much too small for your use case"?. MQTT could meet all of the stated requirements but, as FrankP points out, there are alternatives that offer more flexibility (there is not really enough info in the question to comment further).